# JBO-25003: Object AppModuleDataControl of type DataControl is not found

Tags: oracle-adf

Hi I am trying get the data from database into af:selectOneChoice. I have created a query based VO and accessing it from appmodule. When I try to load the page it is giving me the below error

```
oracle.jbo.NoObjException: JBO-25003: Object AppModuleDataControl of type DataControl is not found.
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.getDataControl(DCIteratorBinding.java:2424)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.getAttributeDefs(DCIteratorBinding.java:3201)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlValueBinding.fetchAttrDefs(JUCtrlValueBinding.java:510)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlValueBinding.getAttributeDefs(JUCtrlValueBinding.java:461)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlListBinding.getAttributeDefs(JUCtrlListBinding.java:2957)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlValueBinding.getAttributeDef(JUCtrlValueBinding.java:537)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlValueBinding.getAttributeDef(JUCtrlValueBinding.java:527)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlValueBinding$1JUAttributeDefHintsMap.<init>(JUCtrlValueBinding.java:3928)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlValueBinding.getAttributeHintsMap(JUCtrlValueBinding.java:4030)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlValueBinding.getHints(JUCtrlValueBinding.java:2452)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlValueBinding.internalGet(JUCtrlValueBinding.java:2287)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlListBinding.internalGet(JUCtrlListBinding.java:3705)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlListBinding.internalGet(FacesCtrlListBinding.java:310)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCControlBinding.get(DCControlBinding.java:749)
at javax.el.MapELResolver.getValue(MapELResolver.java:164)
```

Could someone please help me in this trying this.

Comment: I would need a lot more to go on. I need to know version, steps you took to arrive at this point. Do you actually know what you are doing with ADF or just starting out? Have you ever created a working DC from a VO via an App Module? Did you maybe delete the VO from the AM and then not update the page using the data control? How are you adding the VO collection to your page? Drag and drop or custom API code? Did you google the error  and try to resolve it yourself? Have you thoroughly studied this: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/adf/ADFDC/adfm.htm#ADFDC766

Comment: I am very new to adf. I have created a query based VO and drag drop the vo from DataControl to create an af:selectOneChoice. I tried googling in all possible ways but no luck.

Comment: start with something simple - not a select one choice - start and see if you can get basic DC working. STRONGLY suggest you read *something* about how to use ADF which is powerful, but complex framework. best book to start is Oracle JDeveloper 11g Handbook: A Guide to Fusion Web Development (Oracle Press). also there are many ADF Videos on youtube, like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xqei4cCp2po. And many tutorials too. The odds of you using ADF effectively and easily and without immense frustration without also doing some basic learning of how to work with it approaches zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot i will go through the video and try.
Can you tell me why the above error is occurring.? Just for learning purpose

Comment: obviously, if I knew I would have answered first! And I gave you some ideas to get started. I have no idea - never seen it and I've been using ADF for a long time. My guess is your fundamental model of what you are trying to do is wrong, or something changed in the VO - AM structure. I suggest you google for tutorials in ADF for building select one choice. A select one choice requires a list - have you defined a list as a model, static/fixed/Dynamic yet? And I still have no idea what version you are using or what you did to get where you are, which is what I asked for first.

Comment: Ok thanks probably i should get into basics first, anyway thanks for your time

Comment: Check your DataBindings.cpx and make sure AppModuleDataControl  has an entry there. This error may also occur if you have any errors in that file.